Recursion call on Listener
When updating, my Listener enters an infinite loop; I've tried every solution, but I'm not sure what might be the issue.
@Component
public class UserGroupListener implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        UserGroupListener.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(UserGroup userGroup) {
        if (userGroup.getId() == null ) {
            throw new CommonException("Group ID is mandatory");
        }
        checkIdExists(userGroup);
        checkForDuplicateGroupName(userGroup);
    }


    private void checkForDuplicateGroupName(UserGroup userGroup) {
        try {
            UserGroupDTO filter = new UserGroupDTO();
            filter.setGroupName(userGroup.getGroupName().toLowerCase());
            UserGroupService userGroupService = applicationContext.getBean(UserGroupService.class);
            List<UserGroupDTO> duplicates = userGroupService.get(filter);
            duplicates.removeIf(x -> x.getId().equals(userGroup.getId()));

            System.out.println("duplicates: " + duplicates);

            if (!duplicates.isEmpty()) {
                throw new CommonException("Group name already exists");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CommonException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void checkIdExists(UserGroup userGroup) {
        try {
            UserGroupDTO filter = new UserGroupDTO();
            filter.setId(userGroup.getId());
            UserGroupService userGroupService = applicationContext.getBean(UserGroupService.class);
            List<UserGroupDTO> userGroups = userGroupService.get(filter);
            if (userGroups.isEmpty()) {
                throw new CommonException("Group ID not found");
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new CommonException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

this is my Listener
public class UserGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String groupName;

    @Column(name = "description",length = 1025)
    private String groupDescription;

    @Column(name = "qualified_name")
    private String qualifiedName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private UserGroup parentGroup;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserGroup> childGroups;
}

this is my entity
public class UserGroupDAOImpl implements UserGroupDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private final UserGroupMapper mapper;

    public List<UserGroupDTO> get(UserGroupDTO userGroupDTO) {
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<UserGroup> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(UserGroup.class);
            Root<UserGroup> root = criteriaQuery.from(UserGroup.class);

            List<Predicate> predicates = buildPredicates(userGroupDTO, criteriaBuilder, root);

            criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

            TypedQuery<UserGroup> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

            // Apply pagination
            PaginationUtil.applyPagination(query, userGroupDTO);

            List<UserGroup> userGroups = query.getResultList();
            return mapper.map(userGroups);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CommonException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

this is my DAOImpl
List<UserGroup> userGroups = query.getResultList() was exactly at this place; it was not moving to the next line and would instead return to @preUpdate to Listener.
This was causing several complications while creating data for bidirectional entities. getting error called Shared reference.
i used
@Transient
private boolean isUpdating = false;

but it was not solving the problem

This would be similar to needing to make updates outside of the current transaction, using a different context. EJB has remote calls you could make from within listeners such as this, but note that it would be an entirely different context/transaction, so wouldn't see any changes flushed in this transaction, and if you trigger something that touches on changes in this transaction, risks deadlocks. There is also the possibility of unwrapping the connection and using it directly - how your provider handles that (by forcing a flush or not) is provider specific, but I don't think it will flush.

When you execute a query, JPA will flush all your changes to the database.
This will trigger your pre-update listeners.
Your trigger tries to execute a query, which will trigger JPA to flush all your changes to the database ...
The fix is not to do this.
How to avoid doing this, of course depends on what kind of logic you actually want to implement, which I'm not really sure about.
You seem to try to enforce some constraints on the data, between different entities. In such cases this is often better done using database constraints.
This is especially true, because even when you just checked that no duplicate exists, it might exist once you are actually flushing data to the database. Also JPA is well known to make this kind of check even harder because it returns stale data from the 1st level cache.
In general life cycle listeners are really constraint what you are allowed to do. Basically you can't change the structure of the domain model, nor can you access the EntityManager. See the spec for details (emphasise is mine):

In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence context. A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked.

Note: this is most certainly a duplicate. But every time I write this kind of answer I can't find the dupes

Not exact duplicates, but when looking for a duplicate, I found lots of related questions and one asking if the quoted section actually causes problems, which I used to assemble a little list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022691/66686
